# Is DBPedia Spotlight still available?

Tags: semantic-web, dbpedia, named-entity-recognition, part-of-speech, spotlight-dbpedia

I was playing around with [NER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) of some texts, and came along [DBPedia Spotlight](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight).

However,

- the website: http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/ is not accessable
- the 2 demo: http://dbpedia-spotlight.github.io/demo/ and http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/demo/ seem not to work
- the provided example url: http://spotlight.dbpedia.org/rest/spot/?text=Berlin&spotter=LingPipeSpotter%E2%80%99 doesn't work either

So is this service still available?
Are there any alternatives (I want to access it from PHP)?

Comment: The project owner mentioned [endpoint update](https://github.com/dbpedia-spotlight/dbpedia-spotlight/issues/388) 6 days ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just learned that this machine is down. You can use the one under http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2222/rest

You can curl it like this:

curl "http://spotlight.sztaki.hu:2222/rest/annotate?text=Michelle%20Obama%20called%20Thursday%20on%20Congress%20to%20extend%20a%20tax%20break%20for%20students%20included%20in%20last%20year%27s%20economic%20stimulus%20package,%20arguing%20that%20the%20policy%20provides%20more%20generous%20assistance.&confidence=0.2&support=20" -H "Accept:application/json"